# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

Tags: php, symfony, elastica, foselasticabundle

Error while run `php app/console fos:elastica:populate`

I try to run `php app/console fos:elastica:populate`
Configuration:
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.1"
fos_elastica.yml:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        medical:
            types:
                service:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: MedBundle\Entity\Service
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

but i have got an error:

````
  Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [service : {dynamic_date_formats=[], _meta={model=MedBundle\Entity\Service}, propertie  
  s={name={type=text}}}]] ```


What should i do?
````

Comment: Can you please provide your Service entity's code?

Comment: any tip? I have the same issue..